# .NET TimeZoneInfo object for Indiana shows they observe DST?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why would the TimeZoneInfo class in .NET show that Indiana observes daylight savings time?  I thought that parts of Indiana where EST all the time.  Should I be using something other than "US Eastern Standard Time" to represent those parts of Indiana that don't observe DST?

```
Dim timeZones As New List(Of String)()
With timeZones
    .Add("Eastern Standard Time")   ' Eastern TZ, except parts of Indiana
    .Add("US Eastern Standard Time")    ' parts of Indiana?
End With

For Each tz In timeZones
    Dim tzi As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tz)
    buf.AppendLine(tz)
    buf.AppendFormat("SupportsDaylightSavingTime: {0}", tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("DisplayName: {0}", tzi.DisplayName).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("StandardName: {0}", tzi.StandardName).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("DaylightName: {0}", tzi.DaylightName).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("IsDaylightSavingTime: {0}", tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now)).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("Current Local Time: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi)).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendFormat("Current UTC Time: {0}", DateTime.UtcNow).AppendLine()
    buf.AppendLine()
Next
```

Results:

```
Eastern Standard Time
SupportsDaylightSavingTime: True
DisplayName: (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
StandardName: Eastern Standard Time
DaylightName: Eastern Daylight Time
IsDaylightSavingTime: True
Current Local Time: 4/26/2012 10:37:08 AM
Current UTC Time: 4/26/2012 2:37:08 PM

US Eastern Standard Time
SupportsDaylightSavingTime: True
DisplayName: (UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
StandardName: US Eastern Standard Time
DaylightName: US Eastern Daylight Time
IsDaylightSavingTime: True
Current Local Time: 4/26/2012 10:37:08 AM
Current UTC Time: 4/26/2012 2:37:08 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana) and ["What time is it in Indiana"](http://www.mccsc.edu/time.html), the whole of Indiana now observes DST - but either in Central or Eastern time.

So there's no "one time in Indiana", but it observes daylight savings of *some* form or other everywhere. If you go back before 2005 (ish - the pages above aren't terribly clear to me) you may or may not find that the Windows time zone database correctly models history. I'd expect the [tzdb database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to have fuller information... that has *several* different Indiana-based time zone IDs (e.g. America/Indiana/Knox, America/Indiana/Petersburg etc)

Comment: Thanks Jon!  So the answer is basically that "US Eastern Standard Time" is the correct timezone id for the parts of Indiana that used to not do DST, and that in 2005 that changed and they now do DST and I just didn't get the memo.

Comment: @mattmc3: Um, maybe. It depends on whether any of them are actually now on Central time. It's complicated, apparently :)

Comment: Well, I'm timezoning by zip code and not state (which isn't really accurate either, but good enough for my purposes), so there are a number of states (12) with dual time zones, so I got the CST for Indiana, but was concerned with the daylight savings time.  And yeah, it's way over complicated and I'm just dealing with the US time zones.